# How to count letters in words presented in each line, occurence of A...Z in the words

Tags: java

I am learning JAVA by practising some basic program. I have a Class file called SampleMain.java where I am reading through a text file one per line and storing it in a  variable called fileWords.

The code in SampleMain.java-

```
public static void readFileData() {
       
        Scanner fileInput = null;

        try {
            fileInput = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileWords = fileInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(fileWords);
        }
    }
```

This prints my data.txt value which is like below-

```
Swift
Dotnet
Java
Typescript
Python
```

I have another class file Sample1.java where I would want to do the below things.

1. Count the total number of letters in the words in the string(fileWords) and store it in another variable called total where I would also want to check that the file should not have any junk value.
2. Using the upper case versions of the words in fileWords, it should count the number of A's, B's, ...,Z's in the words.

I have written my code like below-
Sample1.java

```
  public class Sample {

     public void countLetters() {
       int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < SampleMain.wordlist.size(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(SampleMain.fileWords.get(i).charAt(i)- 25) >= 0 && Character.isLetter(SampleMain.fileWords.get(i) - 25) <= 25) // I'm doing it wrong
                SampleMain.total = count++;
        }
    }
```

Can someone guide me here, what I am doing wrong while iterating and how can I correct this to get the above mentioned count.

Comment: You can use regular expressions to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use code point integer numbers, not obsolete `char` type.

```
"Swift"                         // SCORPION character is not a letter.
.codePoints()                     // Generate a stream of `int` primitive values, one for each character in our input string. Represents the code point number assigned to this character by the Unicode Consortium.
.filter( Character :: isLetter )  // 
.count()
```

## Details

### `char` is obsolete

The `char` type is obsolete in Java, unable to represent even half the characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) integer numbers instead.

### Stream of code points

You can get a stream of `int` primitive values, an `IntStream`, for the code point of each character in a string.

```java
IntStream codePointsStream = "Swift".codePoints() ;
```

Apparently you want to focus on letters versus digits, punctuation, etc. So filter by testing [if the character is a letter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) per the Unicode definition.

```
long countLetters = codePointsStream.filter( codePoint -> Character.isLetter( codePoint ) ).count();
```

We can shorten that code by using a method reference.

```
long countLetters = codePointsStream.filter( Character :: isLetter ).count();
```

Pull that code together.

```java
String input = "Swift";
IntStream codePointsStream = input.codePoints();
long countLetters = codePointsStream.filter( Character :: isLetter ).count();

System.out.println( "input = " + input + " | countLetters: " + countLetters );
```

> input = Swift | countLetters: 5

### Using conventional Java syntax

If you are not yet familiar with lambdas, streams, and method references, we can get the same effect with conventional code by converting the `IntStream` of code point integers to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

The call to `boxed()` converts `int` primitive values into `Integer` objects in a [process known as “boxing”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

```java
List< Integer > codePoints = "Swift".codePoints().boxed().toList() ;  // Before Java 16, replace that `.toList()` with `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.
```

Loop your list, examining each element. If it passes the test of being a letter, increment your counter.

```java
int countLetters = 0;
for ( Integer codePoint : codePoints ) {
    if ( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) ) { countLetters++; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the regular expression to your problem, the sample code as the following:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int total=0;
        int upperCaseCount=0;
        Pattern letter_pattren = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
        Pattern upperCase_pattern=Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
        String data="Swift\nDotnet\nJava\nTypescript\nPython";
        String[] lines =data.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines){
            Matcher letterMatcher = letter_pattren.matcher(line);
            while (letterMatcher.find()) {
                total++;
            }
            letterMatcher = upperCase_pattern.matcher(line);
            while (letterMatcher.find()) {
                upperCaseCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total letter count:"+total);
        System.out.println("Upper Case letter Count:"+upperCaseCount);
     }
}
```

You can refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-count-regex-matches) for detail.